# How to open a new window on a new model when clicking a button?

Tags: model, window, action, odoo-8

I have created a new button on the **product.template** kanban view. The button appears correctly under each product of the kanban view.

When the user click one of these buttons, I want a new window, in form view, with the product variant (product.product model)  id 1362.

The context is well passed to the action. I have verified with log info. But the new window is not opened. When I click a button, I see in the log that action is triggered but the new window doesn't appear. No error.

### XML for the button :

```
<record id="product_template_kanban_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Product.template.kanban.view.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[@name='tags']" position="after"> 
            <button name="open_product_variant" string="test" context="{'res_id': 1362}" type="object" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

### Python for the action :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    @api.one
    def open_product_variant(self):
        _logger.error("open_product_variant")

        resid = self._context.get('res_id')
        _logger.error("    resid :: %s", str(resid))

        res = {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_model': 'product.product',
            'target': 'current',
            'res_id': resid,
            'view_id': False,
            'domain': False,
        }

        return res
```

### Image of the buttons :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to redefine my python method in the old api and it works the first shot!
I know that the original product.template class inherit osv.osv in odoo 8. For me, it means that this class is written in the old api.
Sometimes I manage to override some old classes with new api, but this time, I will forget it.
I always prefer to use new api.

If someone manages to correct my code above (new api), I will use it instead.

### My Python code

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from openerp.osv import osv


class product_template(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    
    def test(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        _logger.error("open_product_variant")

        resid = context.get('res_id')
        _logger.error("    resid :: %s", str(resid))
        
        res = {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_model': 'product.product',
            'target': 'current',
            'res_id': resid,
            'view_id': False,
            'domain': False,  
        }

        return res
```